# How to Reference an Iterated Variable Inside Content Projection of Angular Component

Tags: angular, iteration, web-component

I have the following in an Angular template

```
<component>
    <span *ngFor="let entity of entities">{{entity.name}}</span>
</component>
```

and would like to restructure it to look something like

```
<component [entities]="entities">
    <span>{{entity.name}}</span>
</component>
```

The iteration would take place in the component's template. How could I reference the current entity and include the projected content for each iteration of the entities collection?

Comment: Is this a child? or what does this `<component>` tag refer to?

Comment: why do you want to content project it. you can iterate it inside the child component

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the input property and project the content from here.

*Main content*

```
<component [entities]="entities">
    <div class="content-body">
        <span *ngFor="let entity of entities">{{entity.name}}</span>
    </div>
</component>
```

*Child component*

```
<div>
      <ng-content select=".content-body"></ng-content>
</div>
```

Make sure that you have a input property as

```
@Input() entities:any[]
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/6NiQrBYC3MBj9KJCfdkZ?p=preview)**